# Haskell nested algebraic data type

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I'm trying to model the following simple Scala ADT in Haskell:

```
sealed trait Value

sealed trait Literal < Value
case object Null extends Literal
case class IntLiteral(value: Int) extends Literal

case class Variable(name: String) < Value
```

I model the `Literal` trait:

```
Prelude> data Literal = Null | IntLiteral Int deriving (Show, Eq)
```

So far so good:

```
Prelude> Null
Null
Prelude> Null == IntLiteral 3
False
Prelude> IntLiteral 3 == IntLiteral 3
True
```

Now I try to introduce `Variable`:

```
data Value = Literal | Variable String deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
Prelude> Null == Variable "foo"

<interactive>:3:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Literal’ with actual type ‘Value’
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘Variable "foo"’
      In the expression: Null == Variable "foo"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = Null == Variable "foo"
```

Comment: The *value* `Literal` is a constructor of type `Value`; it takes no arguments and is unrelated to the *type* `Literal`. Did you mean `data Value = Literal Literal | ...` `Literal Null == Variable "foo"`?

Comment: If I use `data Value = Literal Literal | Variable String deriving (Show, Eq)` I get the expected result: `(Literal $ IntLiteral 3) == Variable "foo"` => `False`. I'm not sure I understand the difference between the `Literal` constructor and the `Literal` type.

Comment: The first word after `data .. =` and after each subsequent `|` is a (value) constructor name. The others refer to types. The syntax is something like `data T .. = K1 T11 T12 ... | K2 T21 T22 ... | K3 T31 T32 ...| ...`

Comment: `Null` is of type `Literal`, `Variable "foo"` is of type `Value`. there can also be a data constructor `Literal`, unrelated to the type with the same name. these are just different things, living in separate namespaces, in Haskell. if you write `data Value = Literal Literal | ...`, the first `Literal` is a name of a data constructor (creates values of type `Value`, in that case), the second is a name of a type.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It looks like a perfectly valid and reasonable question.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'd be happy to mark one of those as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Null` is of type `Literal`, `Variable "foo"` is of type `Value`. There can also be a data constructor `Literal`, unrelated to the type with the same name. These are just different things, living in separate namespaces, in Haskell. If you write

```
data Value = Literal Literal | ...
```

then, the first `Literal` is a name of a data constructor (creates values of type `Value`, in that case), the second is a name of a type.